# Decode emoji into two (or more) code points, using standard libraries

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, emoji

I'd like to be able to decode an emoji into its corresponding code points as seen [here](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html). I'm limited to using standard libraries in 2.7.

For example:
 ->     `U+1F1F2` `U+1F1E9`

I've managed to get the first code point using this code, but I can't figure out how to pull the second. Some emoji have even more code points.

```
to_decode = u''
code = ord(to_decode[0])
if 0xd800 <= code <= 0xdbff:
    code = (code - 0xd800) * 1024 + (ord(to_decode[1]) - 0xdc00) +  + 0x010000

print(hex(code))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of [`encode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) and [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) can give you what you need.

```
>>> import struct
>>> b = to_decode.encode('utf_32_le')
>>> count = len(b) // 4
>>> count
2
>>> cp = struct.unpack('<%dI' % count, b)
>>> [hex(x) for x in cp]
['0x1f1f2', '0x1f1e9']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of an hack, but you can use the `repr` of the unicode string:

```
>>> repr(to_decode)
"u'\\U0001f1f2\\U0001f1e9'"
```

so:

```
>>> hex(int(repr(to_decode)[4:12], 16))
'0x1f1f2'
```

and

```
>>> hex(int(repr(to_decode)[14:22], 16))
'0x1f1e9'
```

You must extend this method to support emojis with more than two code points. You may consider using a combination of the above with `.split("\\U")`.

Answer (score -1):

For this problem, you actually need `list()` which will break a Unicode character into its constituent code points

```
to_decode = u''
list(to_decode)
['', '']
```

As an example of what you can do with this, I created a unicode visualization of the Bengali Alphabet

- https://www.kaggle.com/jamesmcguigan/unicode-visualization-of-the-bengali-alphabet

Comment: Note that the question specifies Python 2.7. `list(to_decode)` will return `[u'\ud83c', u'\uddf2', u'\ud83c', u'\udde9']` in Python 2.

Comment: @Selcuk it's not even consistent, it will depend on the flags used to compile your particular version of Python.